# PYTHON: Open Chrome on Bookmarks

Tags: python, web, browser

So every time I open my chrome browser, it loads the company website, and of course I don't have adm permissions to modify the settings on chrome.

It is possible using Python webbrowser or another library to open directly my chrome bookmarks?

I have something like this, but didn't work:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open("chrome://bookmarks")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like that:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("chrome://bookmarks/")
```

I try this on my PC and that works.